# How to extract row that has same value under one column in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

This is the data I get:

**Class Table**
dept  number  title
----  ----   ---------
INFO  200    XXXXXX
INFO  343    111111
INFO  448    AAAAAA

**Teaches Table**
username    dept    number

---

A           INFO    343
B           INFO    343
D           INFO    200
B           INFO    200
A           INFO    448
C           INFO    200
C           INFO    343

And the question goes: What course(s) do both A and B teach?

What I am thinking is to do something like this `SELECT * FROM Class WHERE number = (...)`.

The result should be:
dept  number  title
----  ----   ---------
INFO  343    111111

How do I write the correct code, please help! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is not a complete question, because your actual table data exists as a screen capture, in an external link.  Please include the relevant data directly in your question, as text, formatted with four or more spaces on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
select c.dept, c.number, c.title
from class c 
join teaches t on t.dept = c.dept
              and t.number = c.number
where t.username in ('A','B')
group by c.dept, c.number, c.title
having count(distinct t.username) = 2
```

This groups the data by classes and then considers only records of the users in question. A groups needs to have both users in it.

Comment: `having count(distinct t.username) = 2`  
For this code, why do we need `distinct`? And, does it matter if I write the code like this : `having count(distinct t.username) > 1`? Thanks.

Comment: If you have 2 entries for user `A` then the count returns 2. But you need to make sure the count is from 2 **different** users. And yes, you can write `> 1` instead.

Comment: Getcha, Thank you so much!